# Error Facebook Social Plugin on Adobe Muse

Tags: facebook, muse

Is there any way to add a Facebook Social Plugin to an Adobe Muse website to show a Facebook Page's activity feed without having to log in to Facebook?? (It works for Twitter without having to log in so how can I make it work for Facebook?)

Answer (score 0):

To be clear on what you're wanting to do:

Are you trying to use the Activity Feed widget that Facebook provides? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/

This will not show your Facebook Page activity feed, but will show the activity occurring in your site as described here: *The activity feed displays stories when users interact with **content on your site**, such as like, watch, read, play or any custom action.*

If what you're wanting is to display Wall Posts, you may need to do something more like this: http://www.nouveller.com/web-design/how-to-easily-display-a-facebook-page-feed-on-your-website/